# what is the best approach to Join Tar files after Splitting

Tags: linux, rhel, tar, split

we have the following files , that we split from huge tar file

```
linuxaa
linuxab
linuxac
.
.
.
```

**note - we have only files with `linux[a-b][a-z]`** and `linux-xxxx` or `linux_xxx`  , but we want to compress only the files with `linux [a-b[a-z]`

and usually I use this to create `tar.gz` file again

```
cat linux[a-b][a-z] > centos7-rpm.tar.gz
```

most of the times `tar.gz` created successfully

but sometimes this file seems to be corrupted

any other safety approach to create `tar.gz` file?
,

we get the following errors in case file tar have a problem

```
gzip: stdin: invalid compressed data--format violated
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
failed while , error 2
```

important note

we can do just `cat linux* > centos7-rpm.tar.gz`

because we have others file as `linux-tool` , that we not want to compressed

Comment: It would probably help to know *how* the files were splitted. Also, what does 'corrupted' mean in this context?

Comment: If you could mention any actual error messages, we would be able to determine whether it's the decompression that is failing, or if the archive is corrupt.

Comment: see my update ,,,

Comment: Maybe you should modify your `split` command to use some other filename prefix, so you can just do `cat prefix*`.

Comment: So, that's the actual compression that is wonky. Do consider mentioning exactly how you split the file, and also check that the pattern that you're using expands to all the correct filenames (use e.g. `echo linux[a-b][a-z]`). Also make sure that no old files from some previous split gets picked up by mistake.

Comment: "Compressed file" (or any file pasted together) "is corrupted" could mean lots of things. Perhaps a missing file (part1 part2 part4, missing part 3), parts reordered (part1 part3 part2 part4), one part damaged, shuffling together parts of different files; a flipped bit somewhere, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime the list of files is not sorted properly. You can try:

```
cat linux* > centos7-rpm.tar.gz
```

or

```
cat linux?? > centos7-rpm.tar.gz
```

in case you have other files which start with letters `linux`

but to be sure about the sequence you can try something like:

```
cat $(ls -1 linux[a-b][a-z]|sort) > centos7-rpm.tar.gz
```

`ls -1` will generate one per line output. `sort` will ensure the list of files is sorted properly (if you use split command to make the list)

Comment: see my update about  cat linux* > centos7-rpm.tar.gz

Comment: @yael, in such case try my second idea

Comment: The result of a globbing match is sorted lexicographically. Sorting the result _again_ should not be needed.

Comment: @Kusalananda, "should", but sometime it happen not to be...